# How can you assign a point value to a certain string or character? For example, if you want to assign 4 points to A, how do you do so?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerDemo {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //Open scanner
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter letter grade in class 1
        System.out.println("Enter number of points from class 1: ");
        String A = keyboard.next();

        //Enter letter grade in class 2
        System.out.println("Enter number of points from class 2: ");
        String B = keyboard.next();                

        //Enter letter grade in class 3
        System.out.println("Enter number of points from class 3: ");
        String C = keyboard.next();                 

        //Enter letter grade in class 4
        System.out.println("Enter number of points from class 4: ");
        String D = keyboard.next();  

        //Enter letter grade in class 5
        System.out.println("Enter number of points from class 5: ");
        String E = keyboard.next(); 

        //Enter letter grade in class 6
        System.out.println("Enter number of points from class 6: ");
        String F = keyboard.next();   

        //Close the scanner                   
        keyboard.close();

        double Aconverted = Double.parseDouble(A);
        double Bconverted = Double.parseDouble(B);
        double Cconverted = Double.parseDouble(C);
        double Dconverted = Double.parseDouble(D);
        double Econverted = Double.parseDouble(F);
        double Fconverted = Double.parseDouble(E);

        //Calculate the total points
        double TotalPoints = Aconverted + Bconverted + Cconverted + Dconverted + Econverted + Fconverted;
        double GPA = TotalPoints / 6;
        System.out.println("Total Points: " + TotalPoints);
        System.out.println("GPA: " + GPA);
    }
}
```

This code tries to determine GPA based on a 4 points scale. I tried to do Scanner with Int, however, I was just experimenting if it works with letters/strings. The double Aconverted and such are there to convert the point values of each string into a point value, which can be a double or integer. The values are as listed: A = 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, F = 0.

Comment: If it is just A..F, you can do switch case, otherwise use any key-value data structure such as HashMap<Character, Integer> to store the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is an array.  Create and populate it like this.

```
int[] grades = new int['F' + 1];
grades['A'] = 4;
grades['B'] = 3;
grades['C'] = 2;
grades['D'] = 1;
grades['F'] = 0;
```

Now, you can just look up the value when you need it.

```
char myGrade = 'A';
if (myGrade >= 'A' && myGrade <= 'F' ) {
    int myGradeAsANumber = grades[myGrade];
}
```

Note that when you create the array, the dimension you give it should be *one more than* the highest letter you're expecting to have to look up.  If you get this wrong, you may end up with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Using an array is a pretty janky solution here. This solution will allocate a whole bunch of unnecessary elements, since the int value of `'A'` is 65, not zero. Use a `Map<Character, Integer>` instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, @MattBall, by "a whole bunch of unnecessary elements", you mean a whole 260 bytes worth.  I agree, if you're writing this for a computer from the 1970s, that might be significant.  Just for comparison, the `HashMap` class and `Map` interface between them will take up just over 48kB of the JVM's memory when they're loaded.